# @JsonIgnore with @Getter Annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

Can I use @JsonIgnore with @Getter annotation from lombok without explicitly define the getter, because I have to use this JsonIgnore while serializing the object but while deserializing, the JsonIgnore annotation must be ignored so the field in my object must not be null?

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    private userName;

    @JsonIgnore
    private password;
}
```

I know, just by define the JsonIgnore on the getter of **password** I can prevent my password to be serialized but for that, I have to explicitly define the getter thing that I don't want.
Any idea please, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: but how ?, by using jsonIgnore with @getter the object won't even deserialize ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To put the @JsonIgnore to the generated getter method, you can use onMethod = @__( @JsonIgnore ). This will generate the getter with the specific annotation. For more details check 
http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    private userName;

    @Getter(onMethod = @__( @JsonIgnore ))
    @Setter
    private password;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe because of JDK version. JavaDoc says it depends on JDK version:

Comment: And if you want to be defensive, you should annotate the class with the ignore-getter and enabling the visible fields with the not ignored getter.

Comment: From Java 8+ preferred way is `@Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonIgnore)`

Answer (score 15):

Recently i had the same issue using jackson-annotation 2.9.0 and lombok 1.18.2

This is what worked for me:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
```

So basically adding the annotation `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` means that the property may only be written for deserialization (using setter) but will not be read on serialization (using getter)

Answer (score 4):

This could be quite obvious but I lost a lot of time not thinking this solution before:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    private userName;

    private password;

    @JsonIgnore
    public getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

As Sebastian said `@__( @JsonIgnore )` can resolve this issue but sometimes the use of the onX Lombok feature (@__()) can have side-effects for example breaking the javadoc generation.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work with the @Data annotation

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue.

There are several ways to solve it:

1. Create file `lombok.config` in the root folder of your project with content:

```
// says that it's primary config (lombok will not scan other folders then)
config.stopBubbling = true

// forces to copy @JsonIgnore annotation on generated constructors / getters / setters
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
...
```

and in your class you can use this annotation as usual, on the field level:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String name;
```

**Note**: if you use lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor or @AllArgsConstructor, then you should remove all usages of `@JsonIgnore` with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` (as described in solution #4, or you may still choose solution #2 or #3). This is required because `@JsonIgnore` annotation is not applicable for constructor arguments.

2. Define Getters / Setters manually + add `@JsonIgnore` annotation on them:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getName() { return name; }

@JsonIgnore
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
```

3. Use `@JsonProperty` (it's either read-only or write-only, but no both):

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)  // will be ignored during serialization
private String name;

@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)  // will be ignored during deserialization
private String name;
```

4. Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "fieldName1", "fieldName2", "..."})`

I personally use solution #1 globally and solution #4 for exceptions when class also has annotations `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK version 8 use below:

```
//  @Getter(onMethod=@__({@Id, @Column(name="unique-id")})) //JDK7
//  @Setter(onParam=@__(@Max(10000))) //JDK7
 @Getter(onMethod_={@Id, @Column(name="unique-id")}) //JDK8
 @Setter(onParam_=@Max(10000)) //JDK8
```

Source : https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX